# For which values of $\alpha $ is $\left ( \frac{\alpha }{3} \right )^{2^{n}}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given that $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

I know that it converges to $1$ if $ \alpha=3$ and to $0$ if $\left | \alpha  \right |< 3$ intuitively but I am not able to convince myself algebraically.

I tried writing it as $e^{2^{n}ln\left ( \frac{\alpha }{3} \right )}$ which tells me that my exponent needs to converge to something in $\mathbb{R}\cup \left \{ -\infty  \right \}$ but this doesn't include negative values of $\alpha $.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making things complicated by writing the exponential function. For $|q|<1$ where $q=\alpha/3$, you want to show that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}q^{2^n}=0\tag{1}
$$

---

Note that
$$
q^{2^n}=(q^2)^{2^{n-1}}.
$$
Thus you don't need to worry about the case when $-1<q<0$. To show (1) it suffices to show
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(q^{2})^{2^{n-1}}=0\tag{2}
$$
But to show (2), it suffices to show that
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}(q^2)^m=0\tag{3}
$$
Now the problem has been reduced to show that
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}r^m=0
$$
for $0\leq r<1$. Can you see how to go on now?

---

One can take a short cut from (1) to (3) by noting that
$
\{q^{2^n}\}_{n=1}^\infty
$ is a *subsequence* of $\{q^{2n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$.

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha = 3$, then your sequence is just the constant sequence $1$, so it converges.

If $\alpha > 3$ then, since the exponential function $x \mapsto a^x$ increases when $a>1$, we have that

$$\left( \frac \alpha 3 \right) ^{2^n} \ge \left( \frac \alpha 3 \right) ^n$$

and since $\left( \frac \alpha 3 \right) ^n \to \infty$, it follows that $\left( \frac \alpha 3 \right) ^{2^n} \to \infty$ too.

If $0 \le \alpha < 3$ then, since the exponential function $x \mapsto a^x$ decreases when $a<1$, we have that

$$\left( \frac \alpha 3 \right) ^{2^n} \le \left( \frac \alpha 3 \right) ^n$$

and since $\left( \frac \alpha 3 \right) ^n \to 0$, it follows that $\left( \frac \alpha 3 \right) ^{2^n} \to 0$ too.

If $\alpha <0$ then the same analysis done above is valid, because the powers $2^n$ are all even for $n \ge 1$, so they kill the sign.

To conclude, your sequence converges only for $| \alpha | \le 3$, for the reasons given above (based upon "the squeeze theorem", a.k.a. "the sandwich theorem").

Answer (score 1):

The key is that if $\lvert q \rvert<1,$ then $\lim q^n=0.$ If $q=0,$ the result is trivial. If $\left | q\right |\neq 0$ and $\epsilon>0,$ then: $$\left | q^n-0 \right |<\epsilon\Leftrightarrow \left | q\right |^n<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow n\log \left | q\right | <\log \epsilon.\quad (*)$$ As $0<\left | q\right |<1,$ we verify $\log \left | q\right |<0$ and the last inequality of $(*)$ is equivalent to $n>\dfrac{\log \epsilon}{\log \left | q\right |}.$ We have proven that $\lim q^n=0.$ Similar arguments changing $q$ by $\alpha/3$ and $n$ by $2^n.$

Answer (score 0):

like $\lim_{n\to+\infty}q^n$, we have

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\frac{\alpha}{3}\right)^{\large 2^n}$$

- $=+\infty$ if $|\alpha|>3$
- $=1$ if $ |\alpha|=3$
- $=0$ if $ |\alpha|<3$

Comment: Could you please explain what would $q$ be in this case?

Comment: And actually, the op said as much with respect to the values for which the sequence converges. All you did was rewrite John's post, and also adding when it diverges (why?).  John is looking for justification for his intuition.  You haven't provided it.